# create-react app not updating when i change relative path of files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have created a react app with:

```
npx create-react-app my app
```

Initially i had an images folder but it was outside the src folder so i could not use them then i incorrectly moved the images folder inside another folder inside the src folder instead of just inside the src folder however my app is giving me a

```
'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve from '/some path/'
```

error but the thing is that is not where i told it to get the images from, it is looking for it in the wrong folder, i have updated many times but it is giving me the same error no matter how many times i change the import path. what should i do?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the dev server?

Comment: yes i have done that twice

Comment: Are you using relative paths? If yes, could you paste some code

Answer (score 0):

Silly of me, I had to do `../../path` instead I forgot the center one and was just writing `../some path`

Comment: So it's working as expected?

Comment: yes it is working as expected :)